# Whitelist Domain Authentication Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, dns, middleware, whitelist

I'm looking for the best way to only allow certain domains to access my laravel application. I'm currently using Laravel 5.1 and am using a Middleware to redirect if the referring domain isn't located in the whitelisted domains.

```
class Whitelist {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //requesting URL
        $referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');

        //parse url to match base in table
        $host = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $host = str_replace("www.", "", $host);

        //Cached query to whitelisted domains - 1400 = 24 hours
        $whiteList = Cache::remember('whitelist_domains', 1400, function(){
            $query = WhiteListDomains::lists('domain')->all();
            return $query;
        });

        //Check that referring domain is whitelisted or itself?
        if(in_array($host, $whiteList)){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
            die('You are not allowed to access this file.');
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this, or am I on the right track?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "I'm looking for the best way to only allow certain domains to access my laravel application." what do you actually mean? The user has to be on one of those domains, or the user has to be referred by one of those domains?

Comment: I think it's a clean and good solution

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, the implementation seems to be fine.

However, do not trust the HTTP_REFERER as a means of authentication/identification as it can be modified easily.