# Laravel Restfull Api Security

Tags: php, laravel, security

to me what is needed to prevent outsiders. I just want to respond to requests from those places I have defined.

**Example :** allowed applications and url

```
com.x.app
com.y.app
--------- AND ---------
http://www.x.com
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Best regards!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whitelist Domain Authentication Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567340/whitelist-domain-authentication-laravel)

Comment: We can solve the example for the web. But does it apply to the mobile application?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What's the difference between "for the web" and "the mobile application"? Please add all neccessary information about this to the question

Comment: One is url and the other is package name.

Answer (score 1):

You should explain what you want clearly. Basically, to do something like this you need to check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` attribute of the HTTP header that you are receiving and filter on `Android` or `iPhone` keywords.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If you use any kind of "iPhone keyword", it would be pretty easy for another application to use this "keyword" and access the API without permission

Comment: If his question is unclear, you need to ask for details in the comments under his question or vote to close it as being unclear. Do not reply if the details aren't there. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build a RESTful API in Laravel is via the `routes/api.php`

When you add a route to this file, such as the following:

```
Route::get('/users/list', 'ApiController@userList');
```

This means when you go to `yourwebsite.com/api/users.list`, it will execute the given method in the given controller.

As far as authenticating you API users, you can store your users and their API keys in a database and authenticate them before they reach the method by using the magic construct method.

```
public function __construct() {
  $inputKey = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'key'); //filter input the way you want
  if(!isCustomer($inputKey) { //validate api keys in your app somehow
     die('Authentication Failure'); //kick the freebooters
  }
}
```

Comment: I make tokens for users. Do I need to produce an extra in the applications?